# How to animate an image created with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I have created something like this

```
var pic = $('<img>').attr('src',someSrc);
$('body').append(pic);
```

I want to animate this image to a certain position on screen right after it was added to the body, let's say something like:

```
$(pic).animate({top:'270px', left: '500px'}, 'slow');
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: I think you also need to set `position:absolute;`

Answer (score 0):

Edit, Updated

Added `'` , `'` before , after double quotation marks within attribute selector , `.css("position", "relative")` to `pic`

---

Try utilizing `.find()` with parameter attribute selector `"[src='" + someSrc + "']"` chained to `.append()` which returns `body` element

```js
var someSrc = "http://lorempixel.com/200/200/technics";

var pic = $('<img>').attr('src',someSrc)
          .css("position","relative");

$("body").append(pic)
.find("[src='" + someSrc + "']")
      .animate({
        top: "270px",
        left: "500px"
      }, "slow");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @itay312  Can describe _"It didn't work"_ ? , create stacksnippets, jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: sorry it now works! thanks a lot for the help my friend! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have test this in browse,but it seems can not be worked in snippet,may be you also need to test it in your local html file

```js
var img = $('<img src="http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/36e3fe661d1c4e38885da2fb2c98b1fc.png">');
img.css('position', 'absolute');
$('div#testDiv').append(img);
img.animate({ top: '270px', left: '500px' }, 'slow');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="testDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a "position: absolute" to your image.

```
var pic = $('<img style="position: absolute;">').attr('src', someSrc);
$('body').append(pic);

pic.animate({top:'270px', left: '500px'}, 'slow');
```